# magento SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

I am stuck, off course, else i wouldn't be here :). I was configuring a magento site. When i selected all indexes under 'cache management' and i chose 'enable'  i suddenly get the following error:

The xml config files are all ok, it worked before, i also restarted my wamp server (i am running local). I use Magento 1.9.1

Thanx for your support!

And here is the exception thats cracking my brain:

```
SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

Trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 C:\wamp\www\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Zend\Db\Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 C:\wamp\www\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 C:\wamp\www\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SHOW TABLE STAT...', Array)
#5 C:\wamp\www\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SHOW TABLE STAT...', Array)
#6 C:\wamp\www\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(347): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SHOW TABLE STAT...')
#7 C:\wamp\www\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(378): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->raw_query('SHOW TABLE STAT...')
#8 C:\wamp\www\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(983): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->raw_fetchRow('SHOW TABLE STAT...')
#9 C:\wamp\www\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(2510): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->showTableStatus('mage_core_cache...', NULL)
#10 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Cache.php(58): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->isTableExists('mage_core_cache...')
#11 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Cache.php(478): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache->getAllOptions()
#12 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Cache.php(520): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions()
#13 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1183): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config')
#14 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
#15 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(294): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
#16 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(413): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
#17 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#18 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 C:\wamp\www\magento\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}
```

Comment: So you've checked that database, set in config, exists?

Comment: Hi u_mulder, yes i checked that. Before enabling the cache everything was ok, the only thing that (i) changed was enabling cache. The local.xml file i didn't change. I still checked the local.xml file afterwards because for me that was the only source i could find. Are there more xml files (or modules) which use dbnames?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your effort but i solved it on a very bad way. I reinstalled magento copied my original database en copied my theme files.. I dont have the problem anymore so i still don't know what it was. I will keep my fingers crossed ;)